# Salesforce REST API for Validation Rules

Tags: api, validation, rest, salesforce, metadata

How do we get the list of all validation rules in SalesForce through the REST API?

I see that there are methods in SOAP API (listmetadata) which can help, but can't find anything in REST.

I tried the describe method, but that isn't returning any ValidationRule.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST version of the Tooling API to get the validation rules. See the official documentation: [ValidationRule](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/sforce_api_objects_validationrule.htm)

You can use [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/restExplorer.php?url=/services/data/v31.0/tooling/sobjects&autoExec=0) to see the ValidationRule sObject via a REST GET.

[image]

To list all the validation rules the REST SOQL query would be something like:

```
/services/data/v31.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+Id+From+ValidationRule
```

[image: ValidationRules selected via Tooling REST API]

Incidentally, the [Salesforce StackExchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.

Comment: /services/data/v32.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+Id%2C+FullName%2C+Metadata%2C+LastModifiedDate+FROM+ValidationRule+order+by+LastModifiedDate+desc+limit+1000 this query is throwing error in ONE of org and for rest orgs it's running fine. Any clue?

Error : An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 177495955-277829 (-6049864)

Comment: @ChiragMehta that is a GACK identifier that Salesforce Support can find cause of. Otherwise I'd suggest experimenting with the query in the problem org. E.g. reduce the limit to 1 to see if it works then. Remove all the fields accept the Id. Try and narrow down what is causing the error.

Comment: Seems Salesforce Issue. View detailed post @ http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71539/validationrule-queried-via-rest-api-returns-deleted-objects-vr-too-and-that-resu

Comment: @DanielBallinger Can we mass update all the validation rules to true or false using this method or any other.

Comment: @TheRecruit I'd use the SOAP [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_validationformulas.htm) or [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_validationrule.htm) rather than the REST API to do mass updates. They have better support for working with multiple records at once.